# Whats wrong in my pattern string (Regular expression C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm met problem with string parsing and want solve her by regular expression.
Always as input I'm get string the same like: %function_name%(IN: param1, ..., paramN; OUT: param1,..., paramN)

I'm wrote a pattern:

`string pattern = @"[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9]*\(IN:\s*(([A-za-z][A-za-z0-9](,|;))+|;)\s*OUT:(\s*[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9],?)*\)";`

This pattern detected my input strings, but in fact as output I'm want to have a two arrays of strings. One of this must contain INPUT params (after "IN:") `IN: param1, ..., paramN` and second array must have names of output params. Params can contains numbers and '_'.

Few examples of real input strings:

Add_func(IN: port_0, in_port_1; OUT: out_port99)

Some_func(IN:;OUT: abc_P1)

Some_func2(IN: input_portA;OUT:)

Please, tell me how to make a correct pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern, that allows to catch all functions with separate params in one shot:

```
(?<funcName>\w+)\(IN: ?|OUT: ?|\G(?<inParam>[^,;()]+)?(?=[^)(;]*;)\s*[,;]\s*|\G(?<outParam>[^,()]+)(?=[^;]*\s*\))\s*[,)]\s*
```

Pattern details:

```
    (?<funcName>\w+)\(IN: ?  # capture the function name and match "(IN: "
  |                          # OR
    OUT: ?                   # match "OUT: "
  |                          # OR
    \G(?<inParam>[^,;()]+)?  # contiguous match, that captures a IN param
    (?=[^)(;]*;)             # check that it is always followed by ";"
    \s*[,;]\s*               # match "," or ";" (to be always contiguous)
  |                          # OR
    \G(?<outParam>[^,()]+)?  # contiguous match, that captures a OUT param 
    (?=[^;]*\s*\))           # check that it is always followed by ")"
    \s*[,)]\s*               # match "," (to be always contiguous) or ")"
```

(To obtain a cleaner result, you must walk to the match array (with a foreach) and remove empty entries)

example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string subject = @"Add_func(IN: port_0, in_port_1; OUT: out_port99)
        Some_func(IN:;OUT: abc_P1)
        shift_data(IN:po1_p0;OUT: po1_p1, po1_p2)
        Some_func2(IN: input_portA;OUT:)";
    string pattern = @"(?<funcName>\w+)\(IN: ?|OUT: ?|\G(?<inParam>[^,;()]+)?(?=[^)(;]*;)\s*[,;]\s*|\G(?<outParam>[^,()]+)(?=[^;]*\s*\))\s*[,)]\s*";
    Match m = Regex.Match(subject, pattern);
    while (m.Success)
    {
        if (m.Groups["funcName"].ToString() != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nfunction name: " + m.Groups["funcName"]);
        }
        if (m.Groups["inParam"].ToString() != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IN param: " + m.Groups["inParam"]);
        }
        if (m.Groups["outParam"].ToString() != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OUT param: "+m.Groups["outParam"]);
        }
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

An other way consists to match all IN parameters and all OUT parameters in one string and then to split these strings with `\s*,\s*`

example:

```
string pattern = @"(?<funcName>\w+)\(\s*IN:\s*(?<inParams>[^;]*?)\s*;\s*OUT\s*:\s*(?<outParams>[^)]*?)\s*\)";
Match m = Regex.Match(subject, pattern);
while (m.Success)
{
    string functionName = m.Groups["function name"].ToString();
    string[] inParams = Regex.Split(m.Groups["inParams"].ToString(), @"\s*,\s*");
    string[] outParams = Regex.Split(m.Groups["outParams"].ToString(), @"\s*,\s*");
    // Why not construct a "function" object to store all these values
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: @IvanovPavel: what is the problem? I have tested it and it works well.

Comment: shift_data(IN:po1_p0;OUT: po1_p1, po1_p2)
this is first test-case. Didnt work

Comment: @IvanovPavel: sorry, but i test it in regexstorm.net/tester with all your functions pasted in input box and all works. Try and take a look at the table result to see how it looks with this kind of pattern. I will try in real code, but you must wait a little since I m using linux and a virtual machine.

Comment: Big thanks!
could you tell me how to put code examples in comments correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is with capturing groups. Named capturing groups are the easiest to work with:

```
// a regex surrounded by parens is a capturing group
// a regex surrounded by (?<name> ... ) is a named capturing group
// here I've tried to surround the relevant parts of the pattern with named groups
var pattern = @"[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9]*\(IN:\s*(((?<inValue>[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9])(,|;))+|;)\s*OUT:(\s*(?<outValue>[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9]),?)*\)";

// get all the matches. ExplicitCapture is just an optimization which tells the engine that it
// doesn't have to save state for non-named capturing groups
var matches = Regex.Matches(input: input, pattern: pattern, options: RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
    // convert from IEnumerable to IEnumerable<Match>
    .Cast<Match>()
     // for each match, select out the captured values
    .Select(m => new { 
        // m.Groups["inValue"] gets the named capturing group "inValue"
        // for groups that match multiple times in a single match (as in this case, we access
        // group.Captures, which records each capture of the group. .Cast converts to IEnumerable<T>,
        // at which point we can select out capture.Value, which is the actual captured text
        inValues = m.Groups["inValue"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray(),
        outValues = m.Groups["outValue"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm have a error An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name

Comment: Did you test this code? After execution in mathces i have strange string

Comment: @IvanovPavel: I didn't test the specific pattern on your example string. However, given these building blocks you should be able to get the behavior you want working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9_]*\(IN:((?:\s*(?:[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9_]*(?:[,;])))+|;)\s*OUT:(\s*[A-za-z][A-za-z0-9_]*,?)*\)
```

There were a few problems with grouping as well as you were missing the space between multiple IN parameters. You also were not allowing for an underscore which appeared in your examples.

The above will work with all of your examples above.

`Add_func(IN: port_0, in_port_1; OUT: out_port99)` will capture:

- `port_0, in_port_1` and `out_port99`

`Some_func(IN:;OUT: abc_P1)` will capture:

- `;` and `abc_P1`

`Some_func2(IN: input_portA; OUT:)` will capture:

- `input_portA` and empty.

After getting these capture groups, you can split them on commas to get your arrays.

Comment: I tested with all the above examples and it works for them. You'll have to explain what didn't work as you expected.